# jQuery tab menu

Tags: jquery, html

I have a little problem with my jquery tab menu, it's working good but I want some changes and I realy stuck on how should I do it.
my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tab-menu li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tab-menu li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tab-menu li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(600); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```

and my html code:

```
<ul class="tab-menu"> <!-- menu tabs start here -->
   <li><a href="#tab1">Lementések</a></li>
   <li class="active-tab"><a href="#tab2">Keresés</a></li>
</ul> <!-- menu tabs end here -->
<div class="tab_container"> <!-- tab menu content start here -->
   <ul id="tab1" class="tab_content"> <!-- first tab content start here -->
      <li>
    <a href="bevitel.php">Adatbevitel</a>
      </li>
      <li>
    <a href="keres_all.php">Lementett Adatok</a>
      </li>
   </ul> <!-- first tab content end here -->
   <ul id="tab2" class="tab_content"> <!-- second tab content start here -->
      <li class="selected">
    <a class="selected" href="bevitel.php">Gyűrűszám Keresés</a>
      </li>
      <li>
    <a href="keres_all.php">Keresés a Képek Közt</a>
      </li>
   </ul> <!-- second tab content end here -->
</div>
```

the class used in the html code is used for css style formating. I just want to I can select 'manual'(in the html code, which tab to be active, and according to active tab to be show the content. In other words, I want somehow jquery code first to interrogate which tab is active(I write it in to html code). Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check other solution**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/76LPP/5/)**

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //hide All content
    var defaultActive = $(".tab-menu li.active-tab a").attr("href"); //store active href default value
    $(defaultActive).show();

    $(".tab-menu li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul li").removeClass("active-tab");
        var related = $(this).attr("href"); //store href value
        $(this).parent().addClass("active-tab");
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active-tab")) {
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            $(related).show();
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: sorry but I already try the demo link, it's not working! it's working only the first time when I click on the main menu, but when I ckick second on the other main menu the submenu is not changing!

Comment: yes it's working now, but I don't want to select the first tab when the page is loaded, maybe I want the secont tab to be active when the page is loaded... I write this on my first post... I want manually code the HTML and somehow the jquery code to read from it the active class tab and display the content of it!

Comment: As per your requirement now the second tab is active when page load. Click on link and check updated code.

Comment: also do you have any idea, why my page content is automatcaly scrolling, when I click the tab menu?

Comment: added e.preventDefault property in code. now your page is not scroll. check now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/GcTPL/)**</kbd>

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
 <li><a href="tab1">Lementések</a></li>
 <li class="active-tab"><a href="tab2">Keresés</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
  <ul id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <li>
      <a href="bevitel.php">Adatbevitel</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="keres_all.php">Lementett Adatok</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <li class="selected">
      <a class="selected" href="bevitel.php">Gyűrűszám Keresés</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="keres_all.php">Keresés a Képek Közt</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
.active-tab {
  background: #ddd;
}
.tab_content {
  display: none;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('#'+$('.active-tab a').attr('href')).fadeIn(450);

  $('.tab-menu li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active-tab').siblings('li').removeClass('active-tab');
    $('#'+$(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(450).siblings('ul').fadeOut(450);
  });
});
```

or use HTML5 data attribute instead of anchors

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
  <li data-rel="tab1">Lementések</li>
  <li data-rel="tab2" class="active-tab">Keresés</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$('#'+$('.active-tab').data('rel')).fadeIn(450);
$('.tab-menu li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active-tab').siblings('li').removeClass('active-tab');
  $('#'+$(this).data('rel')).fadeIn(450).siblings('ul').fadeOut(450);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the fast response, yes, I need something like that! I see that in your "fiddle" it's working very good, but on my code it's not :( I don't know why...

Comment: it's not displaying the submenu :(

Comment: @user3488958 I removed hash tag from anchors in HTML maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @user3488958 try and copy exact code from the fiddle.

Comment: I try but no results, I realy can't figure out where is the error, here is my page: http://styvconcept.clanteam.com/projects/test2/pages/keres.html